# Saving example text classification model from tensorflow tensorflow/examples/learn/text_classification.py

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, text-classification

We are trying to use text classification example from the TensorFlow Examples (tensorflow/examples/learn/text_classification.py) . It works well with db_pedia data.

Now we are trying to save/restore the model using Saver but we are not getting where to use Saver APIs as code in text_classification.py doesn’t use Session at all and Saver API need session to save/restore.

Answer (score 0):

This example uses [`tf.estimator.Estimator`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/Estimator), which has a special method 
[`export_savedmodel`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/Estimator#export_savedmodel) for saving.

In addition, you can specify `model_dir` in [constructor](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/Estimator#__init__):

> Directory to save model parameters, graph and etc. This can also be
>   used to load checkpoints from the directory into a estimator to
>   continue training a previously saved model. If None, the model_dir in
>   config will be used if set. If both are set, they must be same. If
>   both are None, a temporary directory will be used.

Comment: We trained the model using model_dir and tried to predict using the same model_dir. Model saved but when tried to predict (Training code commented), got error:

InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Assign requires shapes of both tensors to match. lhs shape= [10,50] rhs shape= [5386,50]
         [[Node: save/Assign = Assign[T=DT_FLOAT, _class=["loc:@EmbedSequence/embeddings"], use_locking=true, validate_shape=true, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](EmbedSequence/embeddings, save/RestoreV2)]]